# Request timeout between AKS pods

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a Kubernetes cluster inside Azure which holds some services and pods. I want to make those pods communicate with each other but when I try to execute a **CURL/WGET** from one to another, a timeout occurs.

The **service** YAMLs can be found below:

First service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: core-node
  name: core-node
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "9001"
    port: 9001
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: core-node
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Second service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: core-python
  name: core-python
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "9002"
    port: 9002
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: core-python
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

When I am connecting to the "core-node" pod for example through sh and try to execute the following command, it gets a timeout. It happens also if I try for "core-python" pod to the other one.

```
wget core-python:9002
wget: can't connect to remote host (some ip): Operation timed out
```

I also tried using the IP directly and also trying to switch from **ClusterIP** to **LoadBalancer**, but the same thing happens. I have some proxy configuration as well but this is done mainly at **Ingress** level and should not affect the communication between PODS via service names, at least from what I know.
Pods are in **running** status and their APIs can be accessed through the public URLs exposed through Ingress.

#EDIT1:

I connected also to one of the PODs and checked if port 8080 is listening and it seems ok from my perspective.

```
netstat -nat | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

#EDIT2:

When I do an endpoints check for this service, it returns the following:

```
kubectl get ep core-node
NAME                  ENDPOINTS          AGE
core-node             10.x.x.x:8080      37m
```

If I try to **wget** this IP from the other pod, it responds:

```
wget 10.x.x.x:8080
Connecting to 10.x.x.x:8080 (10.x.x.x:8080)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: make sure both services are exposed using ClusterIp and you hit the relevant port. also, check it locally.. there might be an issue with your pod.

Comment: Both services are using ClusterIP and they are running. Is there any further debug/information which I can do/provide?

Comment: Make sure the service:8080  is listening on `Get`

Comment: At the moment, I do not have any **net-tools** enabled in the docker image. When I connect to this POD and try to run: 
```
curl localhost:8080
{"detail":"Not Found"}#
```
The **not found** response is ok - there is nothing on "home" route.
Do you think this is ok or should I add some net-tools in order to see exactly what happens on each port?

Comment: Are you using any network policies in k8s?

Comment: I have not created anything regarding network policies. I do not know if Azure creates something automatically which might lead to this behavior.

Comment: When you execute ```kubectl get ep``` do you see valid endpoint cluster Ips being returned for the 2 services?

Comment: I edited the post with the results. Basically, I see some IP:port returned and when I try to **wget** this from the other pod, it responds.

Comment: Can you ```curl core-node:9001```

Comment: Yes, it throws a timeout when going to service-name:port. 
wget core-node:9001
Connecting to core-node:9001 (10.x.x.x:9001)
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.x.x.x): Operation timed out

Comment: Can you access any other services ?

Comment: Is it possible that you messed up your subnets creating cluster and have some overlapping subnets?

Comment: Those are newly created services inside the cluster, but they follow the same configuration as the old ones. For example I can call those other services. What is strange and I noticed now, is that after a redeployment for an old service which was accessible before, now the same thing happens.

Comment: try deleting cni pod. It shoud be in kube-system namespace (unless in azure it's deployed elsewere). It should get recreated and then try to wget. maybe will start working

Comment: I deleted the coredns-* pods. Those were the ones you were referring to? They were recreated, but now I get a "bad address" error when trying to wget via service-name:port

Comment: coredns are dns pods, not cni pods. Thus "bad-address error"

Comment: I don't know azure so I am just generalizing based on what I know from other cloud providers. CNI, also called "network plugin" is responsible for creating forwarding rules for k8s services. Since they are not working it looks to me that this most probable suspect.

Comment: Azure may not even run its cni as a pod as other providers do. Anyway, I'd recomment to contact azure directly about this weird behaviour.

Comment: Finally, we did not find the reason why it was failing. I presume that it was either a rolling update or an outage which affected our public cluster. We re-created everything using the same configuration files and everything worked properly.